# What are the benefits of burning a corpse?

Tags: the-evil-within

In chapter 2, they introduce you to the burning mechanic.  The tutorial tip informs you that burning a corpse on the ground will remove it permanently.  This makes me think that enemies can get up after I've killed them.  However, through the first area of the game, I have been able to stealth kill each monster.  I assumed that this was just a temporary solution, and they'd get back up.  But they didn't.  In fact, they disappear after you move away from them.  So, should I be hording my matches for the worst thing possible?  Or is there really no reason to burn corpses?

Comment: Maybe the enemies don't yet spawn at the start of Chapter 2?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Matches just provide an alternate solution to removing enemies. In general enemies will keep getting back up until either burned or headless. Matches let you save ammo by knocking them down and burning for the kill, instead of using bullets. Additionally there are some situations where you do not want corpses laying around, matches let you remove them.

Comment: I would add to this that if you're smart with your matches you can burn one enemy on the ground and set 2 or 3 nearby enemies on fire. If you're low on ammo, that's a really useful strategy.